# What is the difference between select count(*) and select count(any_non_null_column)?

Tags: oracle, aggregate, count, null

I seem to remember that (on Oracle) there is a difference between uttering `select count(*) from any_table` and `select count(any_non_null_column) from any_table`.

What are the differences between these two statements, if any?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

- COUNT(*) will include NULLS
- COUNT(column_or_expression) won't.

This means `COUNT(any_non_null_column)` will give the same as `COUNT(*)` of course because there are no NULL values to cause differences.

Generally, `COUNT(*)` should be better because any index can be used because `COUNT(column_or_expression)` may not be indexed or SARGable

From [ANSI-92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) (look for "`Scalar expressions   125`")

> Case:
>
> a) If COUNT(*) is specified, then the result is the cardinality
>                 of T.
>
> b) Otherwise, let TX be the single-column table that is the
>                 result of applying the <value expression> to each row of T
>                 and eliminating null values. If one or more null values are
>                 eliminated, then a completion condition is raised: warning-
>                 null value eliminated in set function.

The same rules apply to SQL Server and Sybase too *at least*

Note: COUNT(1) is the same as COUNT(*) because 1 is a non-nullable expression.

Comment: Just for completeness: Oracle will use an index-scan on an indexed not-null column if `count(*)` is used.

Comment: I thought the three possible options were `COUNT(*)`, `COUNT(<constant>)` and `COUNT(<column name>)` and that all three could be prefixed with `ALL` or `DISTINCT` (defaulting to `ALL` if omitted). I'm just wondering what expression can be used where you say `_or_expression`?

Comment: @onedaywhen `COUNT(1)` as a useless example, it's the same as `COUNT(*)`. `COUNT(CASE WHEN a>b THEN 1 END)` as an example that count rows where a>b.

Answer (score 16):

In any recent (ie [8.x+](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1156159920245#1304099286234)) version of Oracle they [do the same thing](http://www.oracledba.co.uk/tips/count_speed.htm). In other words the only difference is semantic:

```
select count(*) from any_table
```

is easily readable and obvious what you are trying to do, and

```
select count(any_non_null_column) from any_table
```

is harder to read because

1. it is longer
2. it is less recognizable
3. you have to think about whether `any_non_null_column` really is enforced as `not null`

In short, **use `count(*)`**

Answer (score 9):

In a recent version there is indeed no difference between count(*) and count(*any not null column*), with the emphasize on **not null** :-)
Have incidentally covered that topic with a blog post: [Is count(col) better than count(*)?](http://uhesse.wordpress.com/2009/10/29/is-countcol-better-than-count/)

Answer (score 1):

In the book [Oracle8i Certified Professional DBA Certification Exam Guide (ISBN 0072130601)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0072130601), page 78 says COUNT(1) will actually run faster that **COUNT(*)** because certain mechanisms are called into play for checking the data dictionary for the every column's nullability (or at least the first column with non-nullability) when using **COUNT(*)**. COUNT(1) bypasses those mechanisms.

MySQL cheats for 'SELECT COUNT(1) on tblname;' on MyISAM tables by reading the table header for the table count. InnoDB counts every time.

To test whether COUNT(1) will run faster than COUNT(*) in a database agnostic way, just run the following and judge the running time for yourself:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tblname WHERE 1 = 1;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblname WHERE 1 = 1;
SELECT COUNT(column-name) FROM tblname WHERE 1 = 1;
```

This makes the COUNT function operate on the same level playing field regardless of storage engine or RDBMS.

Comment: The exam guide is wrong.  In Oracle count(*) = count(1) (at least after version 7).  See http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:1156159920245 (Already referenced by @JackPDouglas)

Comment: Interesting. COUNT(*) shouldn't check columns at all as per ANSI spec. Was asked on SO for SQL Server some time ago too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1/1221649#1221649

Comment: @gbn, @Leigh Riffel, @bernd_k Thanks for chiming in and reminding me to read and learn more, especially since I haven't been working with Oracle for a while.