# MySQL aggregate anomaly

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I was checking selectivity of some columns for an index.
Where is this "ignore what I give you" behaviour documented?

This gives 4,851,908, 4,841,060, and 1,000,052

```
SELECT
     COUNT(*), 
     COUNT(DISTINCT Col1), COUNT(DISTINCT Col2)
FROM Sometable;
```

This gives 4,843,634 unique pairs as per MySQL extension

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Col1, Col2) FROM Sometable
```

The following are wrong: the individual COUNT(DISTINCT colx) all give the 4,843,634 unique pair count regardless of any filler column or expression order.

I expected `COUNT(DISTINCT Col1) = 4,841,060`, and `COUNT(DISTINCT Col1) = 1,000,052`.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Col1), COUNT(DISTINCT Col2) FROM Sometable

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Col2), COUNT(DISTINCT Col1) FROM Sometable

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Col1), 1 AS Filler, COUNT(DISTINCT Col2) FROM Sometable
```

But this give correct values again with another aggregate (like with `COUNT(*)` above)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Col1), MAX(col1) AS Filler, COUNT(DISTINCT Col2) FROM Sometable
```

Questions, in case it wasn't clear:

- Why does `COUNT(DISTINCT Col1), COUNT(DISTINCT Col2)` behave like `COUNT(DISTINCT Col1, Col2)`
- Why is another aggregate required to make it work?

Comment: 1 and 2 as expected

Comment: What results were you expecting? each of those queries should return something different.  The third group should return more than a single value....did it?

Comment: Are col1 and col2 declared as NOT NULL?

Comment: @Aaron Brown: I expected it to be obvious that I was referring to the the COUNT expressions.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA: have to check on Monday, can't recall. I do know the effect of [NULLs on COUNT of course](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/what-is-the-difference-between-select-count-and-select-countany-non-null-col/2512#2512)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you are hitting [this](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62504) regression bug:

> select count(distinct N1), count(distinct N2) from test.AA" works incorrectly
>   ...
>   "This bug happens when a unique index exists"

One of the suggested workarounds is to use [sql_buffer_result](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/613.cfm)

Comment: Good call, exactly what I wanted. Which means I didn't search well enough :-) Cheers.

Comment: Very plausible and concise. +1 !!!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your exact results, I'm not sure that I understand what the problem is.  I tried this on a random table on my machine and got back the results that I expected.

```
mysql> select count(*), count(distinct location_country), count(distinct referer_name) from piwik_log_visit;
+----------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
| count(*) | count(distinct location_country) | count(distinct referer_name) |
+----------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
|    44176 |                              109 |                          291 |
+----------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.81 sec)


mysql> select count(distinct location_country,referer_name) from piwik_log_visit;
+-----------------------------------------------+
| count(distinct location_country,referer_name) |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|                                           932 |
+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.19 sec)

mysql> select count(distinct location_country), count(distinct referer_name) from piwik_log_visit;
+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
| count(distinct location_country) | count(distinct referer_name) |
+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
|                              109 |                          291 |
+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.16 sec)

mysql> select count(distinct referer_name), count(distinct location_country) from piwik_log_visit;
+------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| count(distinct referer_name) | count(distinct location_country) |
+------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|                          291 |                              109 |
+------------------------------+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.16 sec)

mysql> select count(distinct location_country), 1 as filler, count(distinct referer_name) from piwik_log_visit;
+----------------------------------+--------+------------------------------+
| count(distinct location_country) | filler | count(distinct referer_name) |
+----------------------------------+--------+------------------------------+
|                              109 |      1 |                          291 |
+----------------------------------+--------+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.16 sec)

mysql> select count(distinct location_country), max(location_country) as filler, count(distinct referer_name) from piwik_log_visit;
+----------------------------------+--------+------------------------------+
| count(distinct location_country) | filler | count(distinct referer_name) |
+----------------------------------+--------+------------------------------+
|                              109 | zw     |                          291 |
+----------------------------------+--------+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.25 sec)
```

You say

> These all give 4,843,634 too which isn't what I asked for
>
> SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Col1), COUNT(DISTINCT Col2) FROM Sometable
>
> SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Col2), COUNT(DISTINCT Col1) FROM Sometable
>
> SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Col1), 1 AS Filler, COUNT(DISTINCT Col2) FROM
>   Sometable

but that doesn't make any sense.  The first two queries should return two columns, the last one should return 3.

Can you provide your actual results inline along with what you were expecting to see and maybe we can figure out if there is an actual problem or if you are simply misunderstanding something.

For reference, I ran this on Percona Server 5.5.16

```
mysql> select @@version;
+---------------+
| @@version     |
+---------------+
| 5.5.16-55-log |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

EDIT: I also tried this on a different dataset with ~5MM rows and got back the same results...everything checked out.  This was on Percona Server 5.1.43

Comment: When you say "doesn't make any sense", I expected folk to understand and "I got 4,843,634" for the COUNTs regardless of number of columns. The point is that the 2 counts give the unique combination count, not individual distinct counts. I'm running standard 5.5.16. Anyway, I will update the question to make it *clear*

Comment: What was not clear was that you were saying you received a single value back for expressions that contained 2 and 3 columns, per my quote.  Providing your results inline along with a table definition (the UNIQUE constraint was apparently relavent) would have  avoided confusion.   Not sure who downvoted me on my answer or why, but I'd like explanation