# count(id) on Char(0) column does not work!

Tags: mysql-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between select count(*) and select count(any_non_null_column)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/what-is-the-difference-between-select-count-and-select-countany-non-null-col)

I have a column with the type of char(0).
some of the rows are NULL and some of them are empty('').
The question is that when I run the following query, the result will be 0.
SELECT count(id)
FROM test
WHERE id IS NULL

but when I run the following query, the result is correct:
SELECT count(*)
FROM test
WHERE id IS NULL

I have one column,why is that the case?

Comment: Not a dupe I think (at least not of that one: it is asking if count(*) is the same as count(a_not_null_column))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- COUNT(somecolumn) ignores NULLs
- COUNT(*) won't

You can see this with

```
SELECT count(id),count(*) FROM test WHERE id IS NULL
```

Coincidently, all aggregate functions ignore NULL except `COUNT(*)`

Comment: So, `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM test WHERE id IS NULL` is guaranteed to return `0`